# tsql select with recursion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with next structure

```
Id|State|Quan|SellQuan|LastId
3 |2    | 5  | 0      |2
2 |3    |10  | 5      |1
1 |3    |15  | 5      |NULL
```

LastId is referenced on Id field, I need calulate value on next step: take Quan from Id=3 then add all sellquan with Id referenced on previous LastId. thats meen 
Id=3 - lastId = 2 => take value from Id=2 field sellquan then chek if lastId is not null
.In my ecample LastId = 1 => Take Id=1 value SellQaun
Result: 5 + 5+ 5 = 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want. But I will give it a try.

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,State INT,Quan INT,SellQuan INT,LastId INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (3,2,5,0,2),
    (2,3,10,5,1),
    (1,3,15,5,NULL)
```

Then the recursive function like this:

```
DECLARE @Id INT=1
;WITH CTE(Id,parentId,SellQuan,topParent)
AS
(
    SELECT
        tbl.Id,
        tbl.LastId AS parentId,
        (CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM @tbl AS tbl2 WHERE tbl2.LastId=tbl.Id)
            THEN tbl.SellQuan
            ELSE tbl.Quan
        END) AS SellQuan,
        tbl.Id AS topParent
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.Id=@Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.Id,
        tbl.LastId AS parentId,
        (CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM @tbl AS tbl2 WHERE tbl2.LastId=tbl.Id)
            THEN tbl.SellQuan
            ELSE tbl.Quan
        END) AS SellQuan,
        CTE.topParent AS topParent
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
        JOIN CTE
            ON CTE.Id=tbl.LastId
)
SELECT
    CTE.topParent AS id,
    SUM(CTE.SellQuan) AS SellQaunResult
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    CTE.topParent
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are asking for, I think you have a typo in your sample table.  If you make a change to the following it changes the complexity of the CTE:

```
Id|State|Quan|SellQuan|LastId
3 |2    | 5  | 5      |2
2 |3    |10  | 5      |1
1 |3    |15  | 5      |NULL
```

My making that change, it simplifies the CTE.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,State INT,Quan INT,SellQuan INT,LastId INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(3,2,5,5,2),
(2,3,10,5,1),
(1,3,15,5,NULL);

;WITH CTE(Id,total,depth)
AS (
SELECT tbl.Id, SellQuan as total, 0 as depth
  FROM @tbl AS tbl
 WHERE tbl.LastId is null
 UNION ALL -- Recursive part of the query
SELECT tbl.Id,
       tbl.SellQuan + CTE.total,
       CTE.depth + 1 as depth
  FROM @tbl AS tbl
 INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Id = tbl.LastId
)
SELECT top 1 total
FROM CTE
order by depth desc;
```

I hope this helps.   For more info on CTE's I have several articles on my website:
http://stevestedman.com/cte/